# How can both a base class and mixins be used with vue-class-component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-class-components

How can I use both a base class and a mixin with vue-class-component?

Binding functions from the mixin directly in the template works just fine, but attempting to use those functions in the typescript code will causes an error when compiling.

From what I understand to use mixins you have to extend from them:

```
class MyComp extends mixins(MixinA, MixinB)
```

Unfortunately, I already have a base class so this isn't an option. Here is the code I have... is there a way to do this with vue-class-component?

```
// mixin
@Component
export default class DownloadService extends Vue {
  public downloadModel(id: string) {
    alert('Downloading.');
  }
}

// Base class
@Component({
  props: {
    id: String
  }
})
export default class BaseCard extends Vue {
  id: string;

  protected delete() {
    alert('Deleted');
  }
}


// Child class
@Component({
  props: {
    id: String,
    disabled: Boolean,
  },
  mixins: [DownloadService],
})
export default class ItemCard extends BaseCard {
  protected clicked() {
    // Causes error = S2339: Property 'downloadModel' does not exist on type 'ItemCard'.
    this.downloadModel(this.id);
  }
}
```

Note that I can cast 'this' to  when needed, which will work, but that seems problematic if I have to do it all over the place:

```
  protected clicked() {
    // Ideally shouldn't have to do this casting everywhere. 
    (<DownloadService><any>this).downloadModel(this.id);
  }
```

Comment: I haven't tried it with extending a base class, but in an attempt to cleanly solve the mixins problem I ended creating this: https://github.com/justrhysism/vue-mixin-decorator -- didn't submit as an answer and I'm not sure it actually is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed can't extend multiple classes. However, TypeScript also supports mixins.

First you'd have to implement the mixin class:

```
// Child class
@Component({
  props: {
    id: String,
    disabled: Boolean,
  },
  mixins: [DownloadService],
})
export default class ItemCard extends BaseCard implements DownloadService {
  protected clicked() {
    this.downloadModel(this.id);
  }

  // DownloadService declaration
  public downloadModel: (id: string) => void;
}
```

And then call a function that applies the mixin to your class:

```
applyMixins(ItemCard, [DownloadService]);
```

The function `applyMixins` is a function you have to include somewhere in your runtime:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}
```

See the TypeScript documentation on mixins for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

---

**Another option** is to use the ECMAScript 2015 mixin class pattern, which is also supported since TypeScript 2.2.

You first have to define a type somewhere for a construct signature for a specific type:

```
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;
```

Then create a function that returns a new class with your mixin functionality:

```
function Downloadable<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
  return class extends Base {
    public downloadModel(id: string) {
      alert('Downloading.');
    }
  }
}
```

Then you'd still need a class with the `@Component` decorator to define the mixin for Vue:

```
// mixin
@Component
export class DownloadService extends Downloadable(Vue) {
}
```

Finally you can define the class where you apply the mixin to the base class:

```
// Child class
@Component({
  props: {
    id: String,
    disabled: Boolean,
  },
  mixins: [DownloadService],
})
export default class ItemCard extends Downloadable(BaseCard) {
  protected clicked() {
    this.downloadModel(this.id);
  }
}
```